# Oracle SQL Select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's look at the following sql query: `SELECT SYSDATE - 0 ParamDateTmp FROM Dual`. I understand that `ParamDateTmp` is just an alias and that `Dual` is a special Oracle table. But I can't understand what result is expected with `SYSDATE - 0`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SYSDATE - 0 will give you the current date only.

SYSDATE - n will subtract n day's from current date.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Datatypes - Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042) reference documentation, the result type of `DATE +/- Numeric` is a `DATE`. So `SYSDATE - 0` is equivalent to `SYSDATE` (in value and type). There is no conversion or other magic going on there - the expected result of `SYDATE - 0` is `SYSDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by both Jay and Mat, sysdate-0 is simply sysdate.

I have sometimes seen expressions of the form `column-0` as a lazy way of ensuring that 0 is returned in a context where `column` could be null, instead of using COALESCE or its equivalents, such as NVL. However, this shouldn't be a consideration with sysdate, as it should never be null. Possibly just force of habit?